# How to make two Fragments appear side-by-side in a ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

In Google Play on tablets, click on Apps and you will see a ViewPager with CATEGORIES, FEATURED, TOP PAID, and so on. When you swipe your finger from TOP PAID to FEATURED, the Fragment for TOP PAID leaves completely and simultaneously brings in the FEATURED Fragment.

However, when you scroll to CATEGORIES, you'll see that the left half of the FEATURED Fragment remains on the screen alongside with CATEGORIES instead of completing leaving the screen. The left half of FEATURED is still scrollable and its child views can still be clicked on...etc.
How is this done? I notice that this behavior is not seen in Google Play on phones.

Comment: [working with fragments in android ](http://neilgoodman.net/2012/01/29/working-with-fragments-on-android-part-1/) [View Pager example](http://code.google.com/p/viewpagerexample/source/browse/#svn/trunk/AwesomePager/src/com/geekyouup/paug/awesomepager) [page swiping using view pager](http://thepseudocoder.wordpress.com/2011/10/05/android-page-swiping-using-viewpager/) [Horizontal view swiping with view pager](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html) [Fragments example](http://dj-android.blogspot.in/2012/04/android-compatibility-fragment-layouts.